# Are there any RSpec HTML tag matchers extensions for sinatra?

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra, rspec2

I've been using for Rails apps I've been maintaining the hpricot_matchers and most recently rspec_tag_matchers as matcher implementations to test strings with nested tags inside (like, let's say, HTML or XML). Specially the last one is really good, since it uses Nokogiri.

Recently I started developing in Sinatra, and of course, I bundled rspec in it. All is nice and neat, til I found out I don't have certain matchers available like the have_tag (which check tags and attributes values). Well, this would be really great to have in Sinatra, and the above mentioned gems are not usable, since they have a rspec-rails dependency, which has a rails dependency.

So the question would be: is there any tool available for Sinatra which accomplishes the same task? Any Sinatra matchers out in the open? Couldn't find any, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually found out an extension that does the job...

https://github.com/kucaahbe/rspec-html-matchers

Should have looked a little bit more. I haven't checked whether it covers everything that the rails rspec matcher helpers do, but most of the important ones are there, including the very valuable have_tag. One thing, though: the specification for both is a bit different when it comes to nested conditions in sub-tags:

rspec_tag_matchers(rails3):

```
text.should have_tag("p") do |paragraph|
  paragraph.should have_tag("strong")
end
```

rspec_html_matchers(sinatra/...):

```
text.should have_tag("p") do 
  with_tag("strong")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this...

[Code Example for Rspec Matchers](http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/s/sinatra-tests-0.1.6/Sinatra/Tests/RSpec/Matchers.html)

Code looks like this there...

```rb
          # File lib/sinatra/tests/rspec/matchers.rb, line 52
def have_a_page_header(expected, tag = 'h2') 
  simple_matcher("have an '#{tag}' page header with [#{expected.inspect}]") do |given, matcher|
    given.should have_tag(tag, expected, :count => 1)
  end
end
```

The point is: **You can always create your own matchers.**

Hope that helps.

Comment: yup, that code belongs to the sinatra-tests gem. But that looks outdated and unsupported. Worse than that, it requires haml and spec (not rspec) inside the gem without requiring them as gem dependencies (and anyways, I don't use neither of them, I want to parse text anywhere, not only on view generation regardless of rendering engine).

Comment: That wasn't really the point of the answer,  It was really and literally "Code like this" you can create your own... Unfortunately, I think you looked too far into it, I was simply trying to credit the snippet to the owning author.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Capybara](http://jnicklas.github.com/capybara/) when testing a sinatra app (or any rack app, for that matter).  Capybara includes several matchers that would probably meet your needs:

- `have_selector('table tr')`
- `have_xpath('//table/tr')`
- `have_css('table tr.foo')`

Comment: I thought about that, but Capybara is more of an integration test solution, and therefore their selectors are more of an html markup check. Besides, I would bundle more than markup check. I wanted something more core to check any kind of markup, like let's say, metatag markup on SVG files and such. The gem I mentioned only depends from nokogiri, which makes it much performant and also badly named (it checks more than just html).